# How to make border for UL if Li has style "float:left;"?

Tags: html, css

My css for ul is:

```
ul {list-style-type: none; margin:auto; border-top: 1px solid #0093a7; border-bottom: 1px solid #0093a7; margin: 20px 0;}
ul li {float:left; padding:5px;}
```

The UL tag:

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now both borders are on the top of the UL.
How to make bottom border then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to apply `overflow:hidden` to your `ul` so that your floats are cleared and are contained within the `ul`.

Currently your `ul` is collapsing since it contains only floated elements.

If you need to support IE6(?!) then you will need to make sure your container (ie. `ul`) hasLayout for the overflow trick to work. You can do this by applying a width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doesn't consider to this question a bit, but how to make border UL length  like the sum of li has?

Comment: @anthony You could float your `ul` as well. In which case you don't need `overflow:hidden` since floated elements will always contain floated child elements. Or you could `display:inline-block` on the `ul` - this will also negate the need for `overflow:hidden` (although check that for cross-browser support).